# Why do I get the error of failed to lazily initialize a collection of role?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

This is my entity class:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seqGenDoc")
    private long id;
    private String label;
    private String path;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CODE_USER_GENERATEDBY")
    private User generatedBy;
    private float version;
    //@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Instant creationDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="documentGenerated",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<GeneratedDocumentFields> listDocFields;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="generatedDocument",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<HistoryDocument> listHistoryDoc;
```

This is my query function:

```
public interface GeneratedDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<GeneratedDocument, Long> {

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Query("select gd from GeneratedDocument gd left join fetch gd.generatedBy gb where gb.id=:x")
    public List<GeneratedDocument> ListGenDocByUser(@Param("x")Long id);
```

And I just call the function:

> public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
>   System.out.println(generatedDocumentRepository.ListGenDocByUser((long)
>   803));

This is the full error:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   fr.etech.eliteerp.entities.GeneratedDocument.listDocFields, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session

However, I got the same problem every time.

Comment: You didn't post an exception, let alone a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@Transactional` to the method that execute the query.

Comment: Or you can change `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER`.